# Hide Date Input Fields in React Date Range Picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[image]

I want to hide Date input fields in react date range picker. Currently, I am using DateRangePicker from react-date-range.

scss:

```
.DateRangePicker {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    .rdrDayToday .rdrDayNumber span:after {
        background: #EB5A35;
    }
}
```

code:

```
<DateRangePicker
    onChange={item => props.setRange([item.selection])}
    ranges={props.range}
    months={2}
    direction="horizontal"
    dragSelectionEnabled={true}
    showSelectionPreview={true}
    moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
    className="DateRangePicker"
    rangeColors={['#EB5A35', '#EB5A35', '#EB5A35']}
    staticRanges={[]}
    inputRanges={[]}
/>
```

Comment: please be more specific

Comment: I want to hide date input fields as I have highlighted in the image. But I don't know how to hide or remove. I am using DateRangePicker from react-date-range.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS file to hide the field, hope this will help

```
.rdrDateDisplayWrapper {
   display: none; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with setting the property `showDateDisplay={false}` on the DateRangePicker element. In this case you won't need extra css. Find more information on the properties [here](https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range#readme).